# Netbeans java maven project builds sucesfully, but won't run

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans

When I clean & build, the project says "build success" and I can see the .jar file created in the target folder, but when I try to run or debug the main class netbeans says "Error: Could not find or load main class..."? I can run the .jar file from the command line.

Edit: this is a javaFx project.

Comment: Please post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), at minimum, you would need to include a pom.xml and your java source file.

Comment: [1] Re _"when I try to run or debug the main class..."_, specify exactly what you are doing in order to debug or run the main class. [2] What happens if you select the project's node in the _Projects_ panel, and then press **F6** to run it? [3] Post the code for the class with the `main()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've partially solved the problem. It appears that netbeans has some issues with javaFX projects. I found several sites indicating problems.

I was able to get it working by creating a new Maven / JavaFX application, then I took the nbactions.xml file from that project and replaced the nbactions.xml in my project.   After that, I can run the app by selecting the main project node and using the run/debug buttons on the toolbar. Right clicking the Main class and selecting run or debug still does not work. 
Thanks to @skomisa for reminding me there is more than one way to run a project!

Here's the nbactions.xml file that I copied that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
  <action>
    <actionName>run</actionName>
    <goals>
      <goal>clean</goal>
      <goal>package</goal>
      <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <properties>
      <runfx.args>-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>
    </properties>
  </action>
  <action>
    <actionName>debug</actionName>
    <goals>
      <goal>clean</goal>
      <goal>package</goal>
      <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <properties>
      <runfx.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -Dglass.disableGrab=true -jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>
      <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
    </properties>
  </action>        
</actions>
```

Here's an example of previous the nbactions.xml file that did not work. Notice the properties for the run and debug actions are quite a bit different.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
  <action>
    <actionName>run</actionName>
    <packagings>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
    </packagings>
    <goals>
      <goal>process-classes</goal>
      <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <properties>
      <exec.args>-classpath %classpath com.edulog.athenaprobe.MainApp</exec.args>
      <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
    </properties>
  </action>
  <action>
    <actionName>debug</actionName>
    <packagings>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
    </packagings>
    <goals>
      <goal>process-classes</goal>
      <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <properties>
      <exec.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath com.edulog.athenaprobe.MainApp</exec.args>
      <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
      <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
    </properties>
  </action>

</actions>
```

Comment: It's good that you have (partially) resolved your problems, but something is not right with your NetBeans environment for you to be needing to jump through hoops to get your project to run. What versions of NetBeans and Java are you using? Also, did you compare the generated **nbactions.xml** that works with your original "bad" **nbactions.xml** that your project was using?

Comment: I added a copy of the original nbactions.xml file to the answer. I'm using NB 8.2 and jdk 1.8.0_131. I did notice that even a brand new maven/javaFX app in my NB has the same issue -- can't run from the main class.

Comment: See this NetBeans [Bug 212698 - nbactions.xml gets corrupted](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=212698) with status RESOLVED WONTFIX that maybe relevant. But that wouldn't explain your problem with a brand new Maven/JavaFX app.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to some reasons, you can try these:

1. Main Class is not declared as "PUBLIC".
2. Java Environment path should be [set correctly](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/windows-cmd.html).
3. Try to change the location of project.

Comment: [1] Environment information does not matter when running within NetBeans. The IDE's configuration is used. [2] Regardless of that, the OP stated that everything works when run from the command line.